# Can Procmail be configured to get rid of mail after it is passed to a script?

Tags: postfix, procmail

I have Postfix installed and configured to pass mail to Procmail. I have Procmail configured to pass the email to a Python script. I also notice that Procmail is placing a copy of the same email into a file at `/var/spool/mail/<username>`. I don't want a copy of the message to be retained there or anywhere on the server. Is there a way to configure Procmail to drop the message after it is sent to the Python script?

In my .procmailrc configured like so:

```
:0Wc:
| env python3 /home/user/python/script.py
:0
* ^From:.*@.*
/dev/null
```

This however does not work. The message still ends up `/var/spool/mail/<username>`.

Comment: Your second recipe should certainly have delivered to `/dev/null` regardless of the outcome of the first. If it didn't, there is an error somewhere, but without seeing Procmail's log file, it's impossible to say more. Perhaps see also http://www.iki.fi/era/mail/procmail-debug.html

Comment: Belatedly, if you want to do something unconditionally, just don't put a condition at all. `^From:.*@.*` looks like you are desperately trying to match all messages, but if that's the case, taking it out will match even the ones which don't have a `From:` header with a `@` somewhere in it. (Also, the trailing `.*` is superfluous.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly how Procmail operates out of the box. Recipes are executed sequentially until a delivering action is taken, or until we run out of recipes, and deliver to `$DEFAULT`. Writing to a mailbox, piping to a command, or forwarding to a different recipient are all delivering actions.

However, your first recipe has a `c` flag, which explicitly disables this behavior, and causes another delivery to be attempted even after this action completes.

In so many words, take out the `c` flag (and probably the second colon, too; or name an explicit lock file after it).

The [old (not so) mini-FAQ](http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html) has a [section about locking](http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#locking) which coincidentally also has a [passage about your main question,](http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#forward-copy) and a [discussion of "deliveredness".](http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#deliveredness)